# Illuminate\Database\QueryException SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: sql, laravel, migrate

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6kli.jpg)

Illuminate\Database\QueryException

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No connection could be made because the target
> machine actively refused it (SQL: select * from
> information_schema.tables where table_schema = mocadata and table_name
> = migrations and ta ble_type = 'BASE TABLE')

Comment: You may just need to check and make sure you have started your SQL Server.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: i will migrate database to mysql but failed

Comment: Please [do not upload images of code/data/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question) when asking a question. Please edit your question to include a sample of the data as code formatted text, as well as the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

I think your MYSQL and APACHE Services is OFF turn it on in XAMPP Control and then try agin